# table with column having repliction status in Oracle similar to sys.tables in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I replicated an oracle database on to SQL SERVER. I was searching for a table in oracle which has a column to give the replication status of each table (1 for replicated and 0 for not replicated) similar to isreplicated column in sql server in sys.tables.

Can you let me know the table name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can get a list of replicated tables from the view `DBA_REPOBJECT`.

Comment: Hi anthony, I tried "select * from dba_repobject". it says the table or view does not exist